# How to print random string from a selection of user form inputs javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, numbers

```
var textEntered = function() {
    var input = document.userNameForm.userInput.value;
    if(input) {
        document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML += input + "<br>";
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far and this obviously just prints out the user inputs onto the screen in a list. But I want to somehow store all these user inputs from the form I have in my HTML, (maybe in an array?) and maybe assign each to a number and use Math.floor(Math.random()) to print out a random result. (I'm just making a little/random site where you put in the names of your friends and it returns and prints a random name from the names that you give it, if that makes sense).

I'm a beginner just so you know

Comment: It sounds like you already know what to do. What do you need help with?

Comment: In other words, I don't know the code that refers to the inputs individually to add to an array. So I don't know what code to add to make this happen. Sorry wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function textEntered() {
  var inputs = [];
  $('form input').each((i,e)=>inputs.push(e.value));
  if (inputs) {
    document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML += inputs[Math.floor(Math.random()*inputs.length)] + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input value="Hello">
  <input value="World">
  <input value="from Stardust">
  <button onclick="textEntered()">Submit Now!</button>
</form>
<div id="resultText">Submit it!
  <br><br>
</div>
```

Is this essentially what you are looking for?